# Eclipse Plugin Developement: Including JDT functionality in my own editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am making a eclipse plugin. I began with the default MultiPageEditor wizard and implemented the specific functionality that I wanted. Now, I wanted to get features like Java syntax highlighting, error detection etc. that comes with the standard JDT plugin, in the custom editor that I have written.

Questions:
1. Is this even feasible ?
2. If yes, what will be quickest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just sub-class the JavaEditor or the CompilationUnitEditor and add it as a page to your MultiPageEditor?